# How can I get Map getters values

Tags: java

I create Details class and that class create `Map` object. and set `getters setters`.
setdatavalues class I set values to the setters
Then I try to get that values in getdatavalues class. by calling `getters` methord.

problem is I cannot get values in that getters. display empty array.
In getdatavalues calss I create  `mymap` object and assign `getMyMap()` method and display the values

```
public class Details{

    private Map<String, String> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    public Details() {
        super();
    }

    public Map<String, String> getMyMap() {
        return myMap;
    }

    public void setMyMap(Map<String, String> myMap) {
        this.myMap = myMap;
    }
}
```

---

```
public static void setdatavalues(){

    LinkedHashMap<String, String> myMap=new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    ArrayList<String> fields,values=new ArrayList<String>();    
    Details details= new Details();

    |

    |

    fields=readNumbers();
    values=readStrings();
        for(int j=0;j<fields.size();j++)
        {
            myMap.put(fields.get(j),values.get(j));
        }       
    details.setMyMap(myMap);
    }
}
```

---

```
public static void getdatavalues(){
    Details details= new Details();
    //System.out.println(details.getMyMap().values());

    Map<String,String> mymap = details.getMyMap();
    System.out.println(mymap.values());
}
```

output

[image]

Comment: You have a different instance of `Details` in each class. Why should updating one effect the other?

Comment: can you please give me a example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`details` that is set values is `setdatavalues` is thrown away and new empty `details` is used in `getdatavalues`. You must pass the `Details` object that is set data to where data in `Details` object is printed to print the data set.

Comment: can you please give me a example

Comment: @KH19 Store the `Details` object in a *field*, not a local *variable*.

Comment: @Andreas Or return the `Details` object with data set, then pass it via an argument.

Comment: @MikeCAT True. I hadn't noticed those were `static` methods.